# Find the count of elements in a given range using Python 3?

Tags: python

I have a string, containing a range of numbers. I need to know how many elements are in the range. The tricky part is that it could be a combination of hyphen separated range of numbers, or individual comma-delimited numbers. Some examples, with the expected count:

> ```
> "1-10,12,14,16" : 13  
> "8,14,0-5" : 8  
> "0-32" : 33  
> "1-5,10-15" : 11
> ```

There won't be any overlapping in the values given, so I don't have to account for that. (ie, you won't see "1-10,5,6", for example)

This seems like something Python should be able to do easily, but I don't know how to do it in a pythonic way. How can I accomplish this task?

What I currently have:

```
count = 0
range = "1,2,3-4"
for a_range in ranges:
    if "-" in a_range:
        first,last = a_range.split("-")
        amt = int(last) - int(first) +1
    else:
        amt = 1
    count += amt
print(count)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have tried till now?

Comment: "1-5,10-15" would be 11, not 10.

Comment: Please add some test code of your attempt

Comment: One idea here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-ranges-to-list/

Comment: Hints 1) `"1-10,12,14,16".split(',') == ["1-10", "12", "14", "16"]` [doc on split](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split); 2) `"1-10".split('-') == ["1", "10"]`; 3) `[int(x) for x in ["1", "10"]] == [1, 10]` [doc on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions); 4) You can distinguish between `["1", "10"]` and `["12"]` using `len` [doc on len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

Comment: Alternatively you don't have to distinguish between `[1, 10]` and `[12]`; you can treat `[12]` indifferently from `[12,12]` by writing `a, b = r[0], r[-1]` where `r` is either a pair or a singleton.

Answer (score 4):

first, we will define the string we want to check and start counting from 0:

```
string = "1-10,12,14,16"
num_amount = 0
```

we will split the string by commas and get a list of values

```
first_list = string.split(',')
```

then, we will search in each item for hyphen seperation. if there is no '-' we will add one to the counter.
if there is, we substract the numbers and add it to the counter

```
for i in first_list:
    if i.find('-')>=0:
        start_end = i.split('-')
        addition = int(start_end[1]) - int(start_end[0]) + 1
        num_amount += addition

    else:
        num_amount += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job for you. But please post your attempt from next time.

```py
In [35]: val = "1-10,12,14,16"

In [50]: values = [int(i.split('-')[-1]) - int(i.split('-')[0]) +1 for i in val.split(',')]

In [53]: sum(values)
Out[53]: 13
```

Just split it at different intervals and check the count of the values.

Comment: You can remove that `if i.__contains__` if you replace `[1]` with `[-1]`. But please note that your solution is calling `.split('-')` *twice* on every range, which is a bit uncalled for.

Comment: @Stef Regarding caling `.split('-')` twice, can you suggest an alternative. One would be just identifying the ones with range and accessing their last and first elements, it would be great if you have a good solution in mind, would be great to learn that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try (don't use `range` as variable name):

```
import re

re_bounds = re.compile(r"(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?")

ranges = "0-32"
print(sum((int(right) - int(left) + 1 if right else 1)
          for left, right in re_bounds.findall(ranges)))
```